# How prevent flutter app to get killed by OS, when screen is off or app is running in background?

Tags: flutter, flutter-ffmpeg

I am working on a video compressing app. For compressing I have used [flutter-ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) plugin. The problem is the app is get killed when screen is off and also when app is running in background (eg. User is using another app but compression is running). I want that if app could run in background or compression could run in background even after app is closed. But user should have control over it, like a music player. How can I do that ?

Comment: I think I have seen some apps, especially for MIUI, request that the user goes into the settings and changes some value, not sure though.